# How to use commands in Minecraft Demo version

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I use commands in Minecraft Demo Version? Every time I try to use a command, it says,

```
You do not have permission to use this command.
```

How can I disable that and get to use commands?

Comment: Normally, the option to "*Allow cheats*" resides on the "*More World Options*" screen when creating the world. If the demo version does not have it, you're out of luck. Another way, after world creation, would be to *open game to LAN* and change game rules in the process, but I believe it's also impossible in the demo. Isn't it?

Comment: i have no idea how, but all you gotta do is use the FULL version and then and only then you can use commands. £20.00 is all you need and honestly that is not a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't launch LAN and put on cheats you can't use commands on the demo version.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the Sonic6351 still cares about the answer (last seen more than 8 years ago), but it hasn't actually been given properly apart from in the comments.

You can use commands in demo mode by opening to LAN. The Minecraft demo doesn't disable this functionality. I checked this by adding the `--demo` flag to the game.

To enable cheats (in demo mode or the full game), simply pause the game with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, press "Open to LAN", press "Allow Cheats" and finally "Start LAN  World".

Once you have done this, you will have full access to cheats. This still won't allow you to disable the timer, however.

Answer (score -1):

Turn on LAN then put in `gamemod c` and
 you got cheats and
 unbeatable and for full version and demo I did on demo

Answer (score -2):

It's a demo version, so this is not possible. If you were not on the demo, you could just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then "Open to LAN", then "Allow cheats: ON" and press OK.

Simple thing to say: Demo version is a DEMO version.

Comment: There is only one version(currently) of the Demo Version of Minecraft.  In the demo, you can open it to LAN, and select Allow Cheats.